Blazor server - Fluent UI - Set focus to a FluentDatePicker
I can set focus to a FluentTextField:

Use a @ref: @ref=myFluentTextField

Declare it as a FluentTextField:
FluentTextField? nombreFluentTextField;

Set focus:
protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender) { nombreFluentTextField?.FocusAsync(); }


If I try to do the same with a FluentDatePicker, I get this error in the console:

ElementReference has not been configured correctly.

So, the question is: how to set focus from code to a FluentDatePicker?
Many thanks and bye ...


If I try to do the same with a FluentDatePicker, I get this error in
the console:
ElementReference has not been configured correctly.

It seems that this is a known issue, we can't reference the FluentDataPicker like the FluentTextField at present.

So, the question is: how to set focus from code to a FluentDatePicker?

You could refer to the following sample to set focus using the JavaScript method:

Add the JavaScript script in App.razor page:
 <script>
     function focusFluentDatePicker(elementId) {
         const datePicker = document.getElementById(elementId);
         if (datePicker) {
             datePicker.focus(); //set focus.
             datePicker.click(); //show the date picker calendar.
         }
     }
 </script>


In the Main component, use a FluentButton @onclick event to set focus:
 @page "/fluentui"
 @rendermode InteractiveServer   
 @inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
 <h3>FluentUI</h3> 
 <div style="display:flex">
     <FluentButton @onclick="() => focusTest!.FocusAsync()">FocusAsync</FluentButton>
     <FluentTextField @ref="focusTest" @bind-Value=value></FluentTextField>
 </div>
 <div style="display:flex"> 
     <FluentButton @onclick="SetFocus" >Focus Date Picker Async</FluentButton>
     <FluentDatePicker @ref="datePicker" @bind-Value="@SelectedValue" 
         id="myDatePicker" />
 </div>
     <p>
         Selected Date: @(SelectedValue?.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
     </p>
 @code
 {
     FluentTextField? focusTest; 
     FluentDatePicker? datePicker;
     string? value;
     private DateTime? SelectedValue = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-2); //default date 
     private async void SetFocus()
     {
         var id = this.datePicker.Id; //get the DataPicker id attribute.
         await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("focusFluentDatePicker", id);
     }
 }



After running the application and then click the FocusDataPickerAsync button, the result as below:
it will focus the datepicker and open the calendar, if you don't want to open the calendar, remove the datePicker.click();.

